# object inner variables does not change

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The `self.solutionList[i]` and `self.solutionList[i+1]` doesn't get updated when I call the following function like this.

```
for i in range(0, len(self.solutionList),2):
                self.solutionList[i], self.solutionList[i+1] = Crossover.crossover(
                self.solutionList[i], self.solutionList[i+1], self.CROSSOVERPROBABILITY)
```

For testing purpsoes the self.,CROSSOVERPROBAIBLITY is 1

Crossover function:

```
import random
class Crossover:
    def crossover(l1,l2,probability):
        # generating the random number to perform crossover
        crossoverPoint = random.randint(1,len(l1)-1)
        crossoverProb = random.random()
        # interchanging the genes
        if crossoverProb <= probability:
            for i in range(crossoverPoint,len(l1)):
                l1[i],l2[i] = l2[i],l1[i] #swap
        return l1,l2


from TextToKnapsack import TextToKnapsack

t = TextToKnapsack()
kNAPSACKLIST = t.textToKnapsack('knapsack_input.txt')
for kNAPSACK in kNAPSACKLIST:
    print(repr(kNAPSACK))
for kNAPSACK in kNAPSACKLIST:
    kNAPSACK.evolve()
for kNAPSACK in kNAPSACKLIST:
    print(repr(kNAPSACK))
```

the object repr does not change even though when I checked the variables inside the function they were changed

Comment: you don't need to return them, they are modified in the for loop already

Comment: which for loop are you talking about , elborate please

Comment: `def crossover(l1,l2,probability):` should not be a method in a class, your code doesn't make a lot of sense. In any case, you *must* provide a [mcve] for these sorst of questions.